# Converting one item of each subarray in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays and for each sub array I would like to convert the fourth element from timestamp to datetime. I tried something like this, but I am not sure how to do it in the fastest way possible in case I had so many sub arrays:

```
        $array = array:2 [
            0 => array:4 [
                   0 => "x"
                   1 => "y"
                   2 => "z"
                   3 => 1589481768
                  ]
            1 => array:4 [
                   0 => "a"
                   1 => "b"
                   2 => "c"
                   3 => 1589481768
          ];
        $result = [];

        foreach ($array as $key => $r) {
            $r[3] = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $r[3]);
            array_push($result, $r);
        }
```

I am new in this, so any help is more than welcome!!!

Comment: Do you mean a DateTime like `$r[3] = (new DateTime)->setTimestamp($r[3]);` Or does it already work and you meant to use pass by reference like `foreach ($array as $key => &$r) {` and remove the array_push call.

Comment: What exactly is your question? It should work. Do you worry about performance? If so: don't worry (and try not to optimize prematurely).

Comment: @simon.ro, yes it works, I was just wondering how I could find a way to optimize it if I am supposed to work with larger number of sub arrays.